# React JS : How to highlight partial data changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React JS dashboard page that poll's a json URL every second. Most of the time the data is the same but as soon as part of it changes I would like to highlight the change part.

Is there a way to determine what parts of the data changed allowing me to highlight them for a second or two?

Answer (score 3):

In your child components, implement `componentWillReceiveProps` where you can compare newly passed props to the current ones. If you spot a difference between the two objects, set state to something like "justChanged: true" and display accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you're probably needing something like this one: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/XdWoBW

```
let originalJSON = {foo:'bar', foz: 'baz'}
let alteredJSON = {foo: 'barbar', fam: 'bam'}

const getOriginal = function(key, original, altered) {
  const obj = {}
  if (altered[key] && altered[key] !== original[key]) {
    // highlight here, if needed
    obj[key] = altered[key]
  } else {
    obj[key] = original[key]
  }

  return obj
}

const getAltered = function(key, original, altered) {
  const obj = {}
  if (original[key] || altered[key] === original[key]) {
    return false
  } else {
    // highlight here, if needed
    obj[key] = altered[key]
  }

  return obj
}

const getFinal = function(original, altered) {
  return Object.keys(original)
  .map((key) => getOriginal(key, original, altered))
  .concat(
    Object.keys(altered)
    .map((key) => getAltered(key, original, altered))
  )
  .filter((item) => { return item })
  .reduce((prev, next) => { return Object.assign(prev, next) })
}

let final = getFinal(originalJSON, alteredJSON)
```

In this case, `final` outputs: `{foo: "barbar", foz: "baz", fam: "bam"}`. Now the highlighting should be done in `getOriginal` and `getAltered` functions.